# Gmaps4rails: map does not show through ajax with erb data feeding but does when hard coded

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, fancybox, gmaps4rails

I would like to use the gmaps4rails gem to display a map of items in a fancybox.
I followed carefully the remarks on the wiki concerning ajax call, i.e. scripts have to be included manually in the application layout, maps have to be loaded in a javascript ([see gem wiki](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/wiki/Using-with-UJS)).

But I still not succeed completely to make the map displayed in the box.

On the other hand as I hard code coordinates in the javascript it works fine, the map is displayed in the fancybox and the markers appear.

Let me recap.

In my index view, I have a ajax call to the items index action:

```
<%= link_to "Show Map", items_path(:format => :js, :show_map => true), :remote => true, :class => 'fancybox' %>
```

In the controller, I populate the map data:

```
def index
   @items=Item.all

   if params[:show_map]
       @map= @items.to_gmaps4rails
   end 
 end
```

in the index.js.erb file, I put

```
<% if params[:show_map] %>
    var content = "<%= escape_javascript( gmaps({:last_map => false})) %>";
    $.fancybox({
            'content': content,
            'padding' : 20
        }); 
    Gmaps.map = new Gmaps4RailsGoogle();
    Gmaps.load_map = function() {
               Gmaps.map.initialize();
               Gmaps.map.markers = <%=  @map %>; 
               Gmaps.map.create_markers();
               Gmaps.map.adjustMapToBounds();
               Gmaps.map.callback();
               };  
    Gmaps.loadMaps(); 
<% else %>
 // blablabla
<% end %>
```

Where the markers are provided in the map object.

This does not work and instead of my map I got in the fancybox the code itself appearing.
Something like:

```
var content = "\n
\n
<\/div>\n<\/div>\n"; $.fancybox({ 'content': content, 'padding' : 20 }); Gmaps.map = new Gmaps4RailsGoogle(); Gmaps.load_map = function() {Gmaps.map.initialize(); 
//Gmaps.map.markers = [{"lat":50.294,"lng":5.857},{"lat":50.294,"lng":5.857},{"lat":50.548,"lng":4.918},{"lat":50.384,"lng":3.649},{"lat":50.384,"lng":3.649},{"lat":50.08,"lng":4.5760000000000005},{"lat":50.054,"lng":5.195}]; 
Gmaps.map.markers = [{"lat":50.8483059,"lng":4.351783999999999},{"lat":50.496,"lng":5.066},{"lat":50.11,"lng":5.003},{"lat":50.11,"lng":5.003},{"lat":50.162,"lng":5.871},{"lat":50.08,"lng":4.5760000000000005},{"lat":50.08,"lng":4.5760000000000005},{"lat":50.08,"lng":4.5760000000000005}];
 Gmaps.map.create_markers(); Gmaps.map.adjustMapToBounds(); Gmaps.map.callback(); }; Gmaps.loadMaps();
```

When instead of the erb `<%= @map %>`, I hard code the markers, for instance:

```
Gmaps.map.markers = [{"lat":50.294,"lng":5.857},"lat":50.294,"lng":5.857},{"lat":50.548,"lng":4.918}];
```

It works!

Seems like I'm missing something in the json data type conversion. But I'm not expert to find what is going wrong.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: try using [jQuery.parseJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) ... but make sure you are converting a [well-formed JSON](http://json.org/) string (your code above is missing some opening/closing brackets as well as the mandatory double quotes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've got what was not going well. Thanks to the following answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/12219016/1100674.

As I use the following syntax:

Gmaps.map.markers = <%=  @map %>;

I get the json rendered as this:

```
               Gmaps.map.markers = [{&quot;lat&quot;:50.8483059,&quot;lng&quot;:4.351783999999999},{&quot;lat&quot;:50.11,&quot;lng&quot;:5.003},{&quot;lat&quot;:50.11,&quot;lng&quot;:5.003},{&quot;lat&quot;:50.08,&quot;lng&quot;:4.5760000000000005},{&quot;lat&quot;:50.08,&quot;lng&quot;:4.5760000000000005},{&quot;lat&quot;:50.08,&quot;lng&quot;:4.5760000000000005},{&quot;lat&quot;:50.413,&quot;lng&quot;:4.371}];
```

Whereas I use the `raw()` method,

Gmaps.map.markers = <%=  raw(@map) %>;

I get the correct format.

```
               Gmaps.map.markers = [{"lat":50.8483059,"lng":4.351783999999999},{"lat":50.11,"lng":5.003},{"lat":50.11,"lng":5.003},{"lat":50.08,"lng":4.5760000000000005},{"lat":50.08,"lng":4.5760000000000005},{"lat":50.08,"lng":4.5760000000000005},{"lat":50.413,"lng":4.371}];
```

Answer (score 0):

Just successfully tried:

```
<a href="#test" class="fancybox">Open</a>

<div id="test" style="display:none;width:300px;">
  <%= gmaps markers: { data: @json } , last_map: false %>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    openEffect  : 'none',
    closeEffect : 'none',
    afterLoad   : function() { Gmaps.loadMaps(); }
});
</script>
```