# adding and updating markers after map has loaded, using Gmaps4rails v2

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-maps-api-3, gmaps4rails

In my Rails app, after the map has finished loading, I make an Ajax call and I get back some points of interest that fall within the map envelope. I would like to mark those points of interest on the map, but I don't want the map to move whatsoever as a result of adding the markers, and I would like clustering to happen if the markers are too close to one another.

Second, in my app I am able to load (by an Ajax-back button) more points of interest (within the same map bounds), and I would like to be able to add those new points to the map (in addition to the existing ones - and as before, they should be clustered amongst each other (old and new) if they are too close together).

I have seen things like [`Gmaps4Rails.replace_markers(newItemData);`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6117344/664833) and [`Gmaps.map.replaceMarkers(markers)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12219016/664833), though I see no reference to [`replace_markers`](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/search?q=replace_markers) or [`replaceMarkers`](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/search?q=replaceMarkers) in Gmaps4Rails' codebase (`v2` at the time of this writing). Also, I think `handler.bounds.extendWith(markers); handler.fitMapToBounds();` is not right for me, as that seems like it would move the map.

How should I go about doing these things with Gmaps4Rails `v2`?

- add markers without moving the map (and cluster if need be)
- add more markers without moving the map (and cluster the existing and new ones if need be)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the [doc here](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/wiki/Js-Methods#handler-interface)

You can do:

```
var markers = handler.addMarkers(json_array)
var marker  = handler.addMarker(json)

handler.removeMarkers(markers)
handler.removeMarker(marker)
```

---

If you [read the source](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/blob/master/vendor/assets/javascripts/gmaps/objects/handler.coffee) you'll see it handles the clusterer for you.

Comment: Don't forget to use global variable for markers Gmaps.markers = handler.addMarkers(<%=raw @hash.to_json %>);